# Make Alt-Enter insert new similar line in emacs rather than make the window full screen

Tags: emacs, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I just installed emacs in wsl and Alt-Enter causes the window to go full-screen rather than to insert a new similar line (eg. new bullet point below). Any suggestions on how to make this behavior go away?

Sincerely,
Alejandro Braun